# How to stop cypress from closing browser after each test case (it)?

Tags: cypress, mocha.js, ui-automation

I have a cy.js file like this

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
context("Dummy test cases", () => {
  it("open Google", () => {
    cy.visit("www.google.com");
  });

  it("search a keyword", () => {
    cy.get(".gLFyf").type("cypress{enter}");
  });
});
```

As you can see I've 2 test cases. 1 is to open a website and the other is to do other tasks.
But the problem is that after finishing the first 'it' (test case 1), the browser closes and then the next case fails because there is no active browser.

Can you help me how to stop cypress from closing the browser after the execution of each test case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found Cypress is quite opinionated about some things, one at the top of the list is "test isolation" which means one test must not influence another test.

Note each `it()` is a test.

To make your code work, you must turn off test isolation.

If the `cypress.config.js` file add the option

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    testIsolation: false,
  },
})
```

Same if you are using `typescript`.

Answer (score 1):

This got added in the new Version Cypress 12.0.0, in their
[Changelogs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#12-0-0) its at the feature section:
*`Added a new configuration option called testIsolation, which defaults to true.`*

As @Joylette already said, in your config file just use `testIsolation: false` to deactivate it. If you ever use an older version use `testIsolation: off`, they renamed it in the newest version.